# ruby monkey patching a module's classmethod

Tags: ruby, module, monkeypatching

A gem I'm using (gem "A") relies on another gem (gem "B") whose method I'm trying to patch. When I patch gem "B" and call a method from gem "A", the monkey patch is ignored. My patch looks like the following:

```
module B
  class<< self
    def patched_method()
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

I've inserted statements throughout to print the location of the method, using the form

```
puts B.method(:patched_method).source_location
```

When called before the patch, it points to the location of gem "B". After the patch it points to the location where I've defined the patch, yet it still doesn't call my patch!

Right now my patch just calls `raise` so I can verify that it's being called, but I've also tried printing text and calling my actual patch code, none of which works. What am I doing wrong?

#### Gem and code specifics

I'm trying to patch the [`Numerizer` gem's `numerize` method](https://github.com/jduff/numerizer/blob/master/lib/numerizer.rb#L109) which is used by the [`Chronic` gem](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic).

I've tried to patch multiple ways, but the most recent were:

```
module NumerizerExpand
  module ClassMethods
    def self.numerize(value)
      raise
    end
  end

  def self.included(receiver)
    receiver.extend ClassMethods
  end
end
Numerizer.send(:include, NumerizerExpand)
```

and

```
Numerizer.instance_eval do
  class<< self
    def my_numerize(value)
      puts "here"
      raise
    end
    alias_method :numerize, :my_numerize
  end
end
```

For the second method, I've tried using both `instance_eval` and `module_eval` but neither seem to work.

[I've created a gist on github](https://gist.github.com/JesseBuesking/3b641e9c6328e03494bf4e56fbfd776f) that contains the script I'm running to test this.

Comment: why not patching `module A`? Make your life easier :)

Comment: How are you including / evaling / prepending the patch?

Comment: It is hard to help you, maybe you can say which actual gem's you working with and provide some actual code examples?

Comment: @akuhn I've updated my question with more specifics that might help.

Comment: `numerize` is a class method in Numerizer, have you tried `class_eval`?

Comment: `require 'numerizer'; def Numerizer.numerize; raise end`. Make sure your require chronic later or you can force require it using `load`

Comment: @ZhongZheng I have tried it with `class_eval` and just tried it again to double check, and it does not work.

Comment: @AmolPujari requiring chronic after the monkey patch does not help. I even tried using load (it requires a filepath), but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're patching the wrong class :)

```
require 'numerizer'
require 'chronic'

puts Chronic::Numerizer.method(:numerize).source_location


class Chronic::Numerizer
    def self.numerize(value)
      puts "here"
      raise
    end
end

puts Chronic::Numerizer.method(:numerize).source_location

#p Chronic::Numerizer.numerize(3)
p Chronic.parse('January 2nd')
```

outputs

```
bbozo@eva:~/dev/SO_question_1$ ruby wii.rb
/home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/chronic-0.10.2/lib/chronic/numerizer.rb
72
wii.rb
8
here
wii.rb:10:in `numerize': unhandled exception
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/chronic-0.10.2/lib/chronic/parser.rb:100:in `pre_normalize'
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/chronic-0.10.2/lib/chronic/parser.rb:226:in `tokenize'
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/chronic-0.10.2/lib/chronic/parser.rb:60:in `parse'
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/chronic-0.10.2/lib/chronic.rb:90:in `parse'
        from wii.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Apparently the `chronic` team decided they don't want to maintain one class as a separate dependency and they just copy-pasted it and included it into the namespace.

You were patching a gem which is in reality not used by `chronic`. A swine's trick :) but reasonable for the `chronic` people to do.

Comment: You rock! The issue is that the latest gem release is way behind master, and that release still has the logic for numerizer within the chronic library. They extracted it into it's own library and updated chronic to use it, but they haven't created a new release since then... so when I pulled and searched chronic for uses of Numerizer I was looking at the wrong commit (master). Going forward, I need to look at the code in my gems folder locally since it's the source of truth. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

`Numerizer` is a class and `numerize` is a method.
You can not use module to override class method because ruby looks for methods in following order:

- class
- included / exteneded modules
- parent class
- parent's class modules
- ...
- Object
- modules which Object has included
- BasicObject

This should be very simple to do, not sure if you have tried it?

```
class Numerizer
  def self.numerize(string)
    # override it here
  end
end
```

I expect this to work, unless you first do this and then `require 'numerizer'`
In that case you will override your changes.

PS. 
I am sorry I haven't tested this, but I can't be bothered to install a gem which requires me to run `sudo gem sources -a http://gemcutter.org` 
I don't know how to reverse that operation and won't google.

PPS.
I'd be really surprised if this wouldn't work.

Comment: This was actually one of the first things I tried, and it does not actually work. I just tried it again to double check, and it still does not work.

Comment: have you investigated with pry-byebug?

Comment: In what way? If I set a breakpoint and walk the code, when chronic calls numerize it doesn't go to the monkey-patched method which confirms the issue.